# SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-33) null: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: mysql, jsf, primefaces, maven

Estoy intentando crear un filtro para una tabla de datos. Quiero que el filtro funcione con todas las palabras clave contenidas en la tabla de datos.

Busqué problemas similares y todo lo que encontré fue la posible falta de filterBy = "# {}" en las columnas, agregué todos, pero aún no funciona

Estoy siguiendo ejemplos en: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml pero no puedo hacer que funcione

El problema es que cuando entro con cualquier palabra clave, la tabla de datos es clara y muestra el mensaje "Nenhum equipamento encontrado", si elimino la palabra clave, todos los resultados no regresan y el mensaje "Nenhum equipamento encontrado" se mantiene.

Como puedó resolver esté problema ?

**XHTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                 <p:outputLabel for="ip_estrategia" value="#{idm.idea_nueva_lbEstrategia}"
                                       styleClass="col-sm-3 control-label #{ideasController.editable?'text-muted': ''}"/>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">  
     <p:dataTable id="ip_estrategia" 
                      rows="5" 
                      var="reg" 
                      value="#{ideasController.listaEstrategia}" 
                      rowKey="#{reg.textoPreguntaEstrategia}" 
                      rowStatePreserved = "true"
                      style="margin-bottom:0">
                         <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:30px;text-align:center"/>
                         
                         <p:column   heit="150" headerText="#{idm.usuario_grafica_Xaxis}">
                         <h:outputText value="#{reg.textoPreguntaEstrategia}" /> 
                         </p:column>
                 
    
                             </p:dataTable>
                         
                            <p:message for="ip_estrategia" display="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
public class EncuestaEstrategia implements Serializable,Comparable<EncuestaEstrategia>  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected EncuestaPKES encuestaPKES;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CATEGORIA_PREGUNTA_ESTRATEGIA")
    private int categoriaPreguntaEstrategia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "SUBCATEGORIA_PREGUNTA_ESTRATEGIA")
    private int subcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "VALOR_OPCION_ESTRATEGIA")
    private int valorOpcionEstrategia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 300)
    @Column(name = "TEXTO_PREGUNTA_ESTRATEGIA")
    private String textoPreguntaEstrategia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 300)
    @Column(name = "TEXTO_OPCION_ESTRATEGIA")
    private String textoOpcionEstrategia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_CATEGORIA_ESTRATEGIA")
    private String nombreCategoriaEstrategia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_SUBCATEGORIA_ESTRATEGIA")
    private String nombreSubcategoriaEstrategia;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "encuestaestrategiaCollection")
    private Collection<Ideas> ideasCollection;


    public EncuestaEstrategia() {
    }

    public EncuestaEstrategia(EncuestaPKES encuestaPKES) {
        this.encuestaPKES = encuestaPKES;
    }

    public EncuestaEstrategia(EncuestaPKES encuestaPKES, int categoriaPreguntaEstrategia, int subcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia, int valorOpcionEstrategia, String textoPreguntaEstrategia,
                    String textoOpcionEstrategia, String nombreCategoriaEstrategia, String nombreSubcategoriaEstrategia) {
        this.encuestaPKES = encuestaPKES;
        this.categoriaPreguntaEstrategia = categoriaPreguntaEstrategia;
        this.subcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia = subcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia;
        this.valorOpcionEstrategia = valorOpcionEstrategia;
        this.textoPreguntaEstrategia = textoPreguntaEstrategia;
        this.textoOpcionEstrategia = textoOpcionEstrategia;
        this.nombreCategoriaEstrategia = nombreCategoriaEstrategia;
        this.nombreSubcategoriaEstrategia = nombreSubcategoriaEstrategia;
    }

    public EncuestaEstrategia(int idPreguntaEstrategia, int idOpcionEstrategia) {
        encuestaPKES = new EncuestaPKES(idPreguntaEstrategia, idOpcionEstrategia);
    }

    public EncuestaPKES getEncuestaPKES() {
        return encuestaPKES;
    }

    public void setEncuestaPKES(EncuestaPKES encuestaPKES) {
        this.encuestaPKES = encuestaPKES;
    }

    public int getCategoriaPreguntaEstrategia() {
        return categoriaPreguntaEstrategia;
    }

    public void setCategoriaPreguntaEstrategia(int categoriaPreguntaEstrategia) {
        this.categoriaPreguntaEstrategia = categoriaPreguntaEstrategia;
    }

    public int getSubcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia() {
        return subcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia;
    }

    public void setSubcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia(int subcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia) {
        this.subcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia = subcategoriaPreguntaEstrategia;
    }

    public int getValorOpcionEstrategia() {
        return valorOpcionEstrategia;
    }

    public void setValorOpcionEstrategia(int valorOpcionEstrategia) {
        this.valorOpcionEstrategia = valorOpcionEstrategia;
    }

    public String getTextoPreguntaEstrategia() {
        return textoPreguntaEstrategia;
    }

    public void setTextoPreguntaEstrategia(String textoPreguntaEstrategia) {
        this.textoPreguntaEstrategia = textoPreguntaEstrategia;
    }

    public String getTextoOpcionEstrategia() {
        return textoOpcionEstrategia;
    }

    public void setTextoOpcionEstrategia(String textoOpcionEstrategia) {
        this.textoOpcionEstrategia = textoOpcionEstrategia;
    }

    public String getNombreCategoriaEstrategia() {
        return nombreCategoriaEstrategia;
    }

    public void setNombreCategoriaEstrategia(String nombreCategoriaEstrategia) {
        this.nombreCategoriaEstrategia = nombreCategoriaEstrategia;
    }

    public String getNombreSubcategoriaEstrategia() {
        return nombreSubcategoriaEstrategia;
    }

    public void setNombreSubcategoriaEstrategia(String nombreSubcategoriaEstrategia) {
        this.nombreSubcategoriaEstrategia = nombreSubcategoriaEstrategia;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Ideas> getIdeasCollection() {
        return ideasCollection;
    }

    public void setIdeasCollection(Collection<Ideas> ideasCollection) {
        this.ideasCollection = ideasCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += encuestaPKES != null ? encuestaPKES.hashCode() : 0;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof EncuestaEstrategia)) {
            return false;
        }
        final EncuestaEstrategia other = (EncuestaEstrategia) object;
        if (encuestaPKES == null && other.encuestaPKES != null || encuestaPKES != null && !encuestaPKES.equals(other.encuestaPKES)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.innovapp.entity.empresa.EncuestaEstrategia[ encuestaPKES=" + encuestaPKES + " ]";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(EncuestaEstrategia o) {
        if(valorOpcionEstrategia>o.valorOpcionEstrategia) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(valorOpcionEstrategia<o.valorOpcionEstrategia) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**ERROR**

```
    10:26:14,038 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-33) null: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:63)
            at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:48)
            at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:62)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:832)
            at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:281)
            at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1222)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:929)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
            at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at com.innovapp.conf.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:58)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
            at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
            at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


10:26:14,044 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-33) Could not handle exception!: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No default error page (Status 500 or java.lang.Throwable) and no error page for type "class java.lang.NullPointerException" defined!
    at org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.handleRedirect(PrimeExceptionHandler.java:317)
    at org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.handle(PrimeExceptionHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.innovapp.conf.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que el código se comparte como texto, no como imagen. Por favor, edita tu pregunta. Lo otro, debes añadir el código relevante del backing bean porque le estás entregando algo nulo al datatable

Comment: vale gracias soy nuevo en esta plataforma.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya averiguando mas solucione el error.

solo fue en el XHTML

selection="#{ideasController.listaEstrategiasSeleccion}"

faltaba llamar la lista.